# why the camera backward is equivalent to moving the whole world forward?

Tags: opengl

Opengl superbible 4th Edition.page 164

> To apply a camera transformation, we take the camera’s actor transform and flip it so that
>   moving the camera backward is equivalent to moving the whole world forward. Similarly,
>   turning to the left is equivalent to rotating the whole world to the right.

I can't understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematically there is only one correct answer. It is defined that after transforming to `eye-space` by multiplying a `world-space` position by the `view-matrix`, the resulting vector is interpreted relative to the origin (the position in space where the camera conceptually is located relative to the aforementioned point).

What SuperBible states is mathematically just a negation of translation in some direction, which is what you will automatically get when using functions that compute a `view-matrix` like `gluLookAt()` or `glmLookAt()` (although GLU is a lib layered on legacy GL stuff, mathematically the two are identical).

Have a look at the API ref for `gluLookAt()`. You'll see that the first step is setting up an ortho-normal base of the `eye-space` which first results in a 4x4 matrix basically only encoding the upper 3x3 rotation matrix. The second is multiplying the former matrix by a translation matrix. In terms of legacy functions, this can be expressed as

```
glMultMatrixf(M); // where M encodes the eye-space basis
glTranslated(-eyex, -eyey, -eyez);
```

You can see, the vector `(eyex, eyey, eyez)` which specifies where the camera is located in `world-space` is simply multiplied by `-1`. Now assume we don't rotate the camera at all, but assume it to be located at `world-space` position (5, 5, 5). The appropriate view-matrix `View` would be

[1 0 0 -5 
 0 1 0 -5 
 0 0 1 -5 
 0 0 0  1]

Now take a `world-space` vertex position P = (0, 0, 0, 1) transformed by that matrix: `P' = View * P`. `P'` will then simply be `P'=(-5, -5, -5, 1)`.

When thinking in `world-space`, the camera is at `(5, 5, 5)` and the vertex is at `(0, 0, 0)`. When thinking in `eye-space`, the camera is at `(0, 0, 0)` and the vertex is at `(-5, -5, -5)`.

**So in conclusion**: Conceptually, it's a matter of how you're looking at things. You can either think of it as transforming the camera relative to the world, or you think of it as transform the world relative to the camera.

Mathematically, and in terms of the OpenGL transformation pipeline, there is only one answer, and that is: the camera in `eye-space` (or `view-space` or `camera-space`) is always at the origin and `world-space` positions transformed to `eye-space` will always be relative to the coordinate system of the camera.

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, although the transformation pipeline and involved vector spaces are well defined, you can still use `world-space` positions of everything, even the camera, for instance in a fragment shader for lighting computation. The important thing here is to know *never* to mix entities from different spaces, e.g. don't compute stuff based on a `world-space` *and* and `eye-space` position and so on.

**EDIT2**: Nowadays, in a time that we all use shaders *cough and roll-eyes*, you're pretty flexible and theoretically you can pass any position you like to `gl_Position` in a *vertex shader* (or the *geometry shader* or *tessellation stages*). However, since the subsequent computations are fixed, i.e. *clipping*, *perspective division* and *viewport transformation* the resulting position will simply be clipped if its not inside `[-gl_Position.w, gl_Position.w]` in `x`, `y` and `z`.

There is a lot to this to really get it down. I suggest you read the entire article on the *[rendering pipeline](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview)* in the official GL wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Image yourself placed within a universe that also contains all other things. In order for your viewpoint to appear to move in a forwardly direction, you have two options...

1. You move yourself forward.
2. You move everything else in the universe in the opposite direction to 1.

Because you defining everything in OpenGL in terms of the viewer (you're ultimately rendering a 2D image of a particular viewpoint of the 3D world), it can often make more sense from both a mathematical and programatic sense to take the 2nd approach.

Comment: By convention, you're defining everything in object-space. The fact that object-space coords end up in different spaces is due to the application of the model-, view- and projection matrix, perspective divide and window coordinates due to viewport mapping.